# How to get user password for database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin; I created a database; now I want to locate the username and password for this new database I created. Note, I am not sys admin, I am only the developer, but I do have access to create db on MySQL in phpMyAdmin. Does my sys admin needs to tell me the username and password to access this db, or I can telnet and get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MySQL creating a database doesn't automatically create a user to go with it.
You must explicitly create the user and grant acess.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: If you have the right permissions you may be able to do this yourself, otherwise you will have to ask your sys admin to do it for you. Just suddenly thought, I'm not sure if phpMyAdmin does anything special when creating databases ...

Comment: thank you, but i don't have permissions. sys admin set it up for me. thanks again

Answer (score 9):

Steps for phpmyadmin GUI:

Select your Database name -> Privileges (here you can see your Privileges).

if you want change password click on the edit privileges icon in the action column

Answer (score 2):

You can access that database with the user/password used to login on the phpMyAdmin.

You can also create new users (if you have permission to) under the tab Privileges > Add new User. Here you can create pairs of user-database with the same name and auto-permission-granting.

Answer (score 0):

In  your situation, it is highly likely that the login you used to create the database can be used to access the database.