# Lost admin previlage of phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I wanted to change `phpmyadmin` password using `mysql` database -> `users` table .. i changed password user root and once i restarted `phpmyadmin` all my databases were gone it was like i am not the admin anymore and now i have only 2 default databases 
`information_schema` and `test` 
[image]

what is the reason of this problem and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly create the user and the password. As mySQL does not support the creation of the username automatically.

I believe this has been answered before...

[mysql phpmyadmin user password for database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266524/mysql-phpmyadmin-user-password-for-database)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following procedure.

1.Go to adressbar then type ip address for localhost (127.0.0.1).
2.In window that will appear 
   Type username root while password leave blank then press enter to continue.