# logging into mysql databases I always get same db even though using correct logins for other databases (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

This weird thing just started happening. I administer a dozen or so mysql databases with phpMyAdmin. Even though the username, databasename, and password are set correctly, no matter which database I'm trying to log into, I always end up at this one particular database.

In the url, the login info is correct. I tried clearing my browser cache. There doesn't seem to be anything helpful on the phpMyAdmin docs or the mysql docs.

I tried running a SHOW DATABASES sql query at the server root level and all it produces is that one db that the logins keep taking me to. All the other db are showing up as usual in the admin panel, tho.

Is this a job for the hosting company, or is there some fix I can perform?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, if you login as mysql root user and run `show databases`, it should display a list of ALL databases (not just the one db you said) -- by the way, what is the name of that one db ?

Comment: @KenLee named: scrap

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at some other questions, I [saw this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3266524/2316731) and even though it doesn't have anything to do with my issue someone said something about resetting privileges so on a whim I tried to login, opened the permissions popup, didn't change anything, saved it, and viola!, I'm into the correct db.